# How to return the derived type from a template class

Tags: c++

I want to be able to call `firstHalf()` without providing a template argument. I've tried using different forms of `decltype(this)` both in and outside of the function body with no success. I'd be curious to see a C++14 solution.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class A : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    template <class Derived>
    Derived firstHalf() {
        Derived result;
        for (auto it = begin(); it != begin() + size() / 2; ++it)
            result.push_back(*it);
        return result;
    }
};

class B : public A<int>
{
    /* stuff */
};

int main() {
    B foo;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; ++i)
        foo.push_back(i);

    B bar = foo.firstHalf();    // this doesn't work
    B bar = foo.firstHalf<B>(); // (but this does)
}
```

Comment: Note `B foo();` declares a function, not an object.

Comment: Do you want to use static or dynamic polymorphism?

Comment: Please explain the purpose better. Also, please provide code that, barring the sections you are having trouble with, is correct and complete. In your example, you don't have semicolons after class definitions, there is no `#include <vector>`, `B foo()` runs into some version of the [vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) and you are using a non-`int` `main` without a `return`. While each of them are minor by themselves, it greatly helps the ones trying to answer your question if they are given a mostly working piece of code with only the topic of the question left open.

Comment: One option would be to write into `B`: `B makeAnother() { return A::makeAnother<B>();`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I fixed the code errors (besides the one line) and made it a more practical example. I'm still learning the delicacies of a well-formed SO question.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the main purpose here is to be able to extend `A` without rewriting the method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern:

```
template <class T, class Derived>
class A {
public:
    Derived makeAnother() {
        Derived result;
        // ...
        return result;
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

class B : public A<int, B> {};

int main() {
    B foo;
    B result = foo.makeAnother();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't even have to provide another template argument in the definition of `B`. But this is the best solution otherwise.